# drupal 7 add_js Weight

Tags: jquery, drupal, drupal-7

I have a module and in it I add the js with

```
if($_GET['q'] == 'workpage') {
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'sb_carousel').'/js/slide.js');
}
```

problem is it adds it above jqueru which is defined in the .info file. I see there is a 'weight' property how do  I get my js at the bottom of the js files??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the weight by passing an `$options` array into [drupal_add_js()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7):

```
$file = drupal_get_path('module', 'sb_carousel').'/js/slide.js';
$options = array(
  'weight' => 1000, // High number to push this file to the bottom of the list
  'scope' => 'footer' // This will output the JS file in the footer scope, so at the end of the document
);

drupal_add_js($file, $options);
```

Using `weight` and `scope` you should be able to ensure that your JS file is the very last outputted in the HTML.

**UPDATE**

Just a thought, you mention that your jQuery file is loaded in from an `.info` file...there's no need to do that, jQuery is already added in Drupal by default. You can upgrade to jQuery 1.5 with the [jQuery Update module](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update) but currently there's no (official) support for any later versions.

If you're loading in a second jQuery file it might be what's causing the problem in the first place, unless you use [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) properly and even then you might still have problems.